# when the constructor will be executed in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, constructor

if a class is annotated `@Service`, `@RestController` or `@Configuration` if there is a constructor with or with our parameter.

I just want to know when the constructor will be executed.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class MessageController {
    
private RabbitMQProducer producer;

public MessageController(RabbitMQProducer producer) {
    super();
    this.producer = producer;
}

@GetMapping("/publish")
public ResponseEntity<String> sendMessage(@RequestParam("message") String message)
{
    producer.sendMessage(message);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("message sent to the rabbitmq");
}
    
    
}
```

Comment: What does it matter? Also, if you want to know, just put a breakpoint (or god forbid, a log statement) inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring, if class is annotated with @Service, @RestController or any other stereotype annotation, it becomes a Spring bean, which means it's managed by the Spring IOC (Inversion of Control) container. It includes lifecycle management, so the initiation of these beans is handled by Spring.

Constructor for such bean is executed when the bean is created by Spring IoC container. It usually happens at the startup of your application, because by default beans in Spring are singleton scoped, which means that one instance will be created for entire application.

In your case, the MessageController class is annotated with @RestController, making it a Spring Bean. The constructor for MessageController will be executed when the bean is created during application startup.

The RabbitMQProducer producer parameter in the constructor indicates that the MessageController bean depends on the RabbitMQProducer bean. Spring will automatically manage this dependency for you. This is a part of Spring's DI (dependency injection) feature. When the MessageController bean is created, the Spring container will also create an instance of RabbitMQProducer (if one doesn't already exist) and pass it to the MessageController constructor. This is how it works in general.

Comment: is there any way that I can get to know the flow of the program.

Comment: if i have three classes and three constructors which constructor will be executed first.

Comment: The order in which Spring beans are created depends on the dependencies between the beans, you can use a logger to investigate it further or put breakpoints to the constructor if you need this information for some reason.